# c++ random number (Visual studio form)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, random

I'm new to C++ (used to code C#) and I just cannot figure out how to create a random number in a Visual studio c++ forms environment. This is the code I use:

```
int randNumber;
srand(time(NULL));
randNumber = rand();
MessageBox::Show(randNumber.ToString());
```

I just put that code into form_load block.

The error message I get is:

error C3861: 'time': identifier not found

error C3861: 'rand': identifier not found

**EDIT :**

I did put the includes in my Form1.h file like this:

```
#pragma once

#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

namespace Srand {
```

That seems to work, however the random numbers are very strange.

3100 3130 3146 3169 3192 3208 3231 3250 3270 3286

doesn't seem random at all, just randomly bigger.

Comment: Did you include missing headers?

Comment: you need to `#include` header files that contain these functions... Read the docs

Comment: Each number you see is the start of a pseudo-random series.  You're seeding with a series of numbers which increase monotonically.  I would probably run `rand()` once in `srand()`, to avoid having the first value "appear" less random, but on the whole, there's nothing wrong with what you are seeing.  The apparent randomness of `rand()` should be between two calls: that the results of the second call are "apparently" random with respect to the results of the first call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must include the corresponding headers like

```
#include <ctime> /* for time */
```

and

```
#include <cstdlib> /* for rand */
```

See [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/) for `rand` and [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/) for `time`.

Comment: I'm a little confused to where you put your include rows, I tried putting them in my <appname>.cpp file (Srand.cpp) and now it does look a bit odd:

    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include "Form1.h"
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <ctime>

(I'm sorry my answer looks so messy, apparently I'm not allowed to use line breaks when answering)

Comment: You should usually include them in your `.cpp` files, where you will actually use the functions.

Comment: It didn't work for me to include them in my .cpp file, just got an error message when trying that. however I could include them in my form1.h file, see my edit of my first message.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `#include <cstdlib>` and `#include <ctime>`.

Answer (score 0):

Because your numbers are time dependent, you get very close results. You can try to randomize your number by applying some transformation to time() like firstly multiplying by a very big number then taking mod with respect to some big prime number.